# Получить все значения строк используя for loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, for

Есть таблица `dict`:

```
   | ID | Code  | Value |
   +--- +-------+-------+
   | 48 | SUMM  | 47800 |
   | 48 | BIN   | 44788 |
   | 48 | CNL   | BHF55 | 
   | 50 | SRV_L | 88    |
   | 50 | FL_F  | AGI2g |
```

Нужно в xml передавать все строки  таблицы через цикл
**Запрос:**

```
for ac in (select a.CODE, a.value
             from M_MUNORD_ADD a
           where a.code is not null  
             and a.ID = iId)
loop
    sCod:= ac.code;
    sVal:= ac.value;
end loop;    

cXmlStr:='<Version="2.3">
          <BillCode>ATTRIBUTES</BillCode>
          <Info>
                <Param Id='||sCod||'>'||sVal||'</Param>
          </Info>
```

Здесь  в тегах Info нужно передать все строки таблицы по ID
При передаче на хмл неизвестно сколько по  id будет строк(код)

*То есть ожидаю такого результата, к примеру по Id = 48:*

```
<Info>
      <Param Id='SUMM'>'47800'</Param>
      <Param Id='BIN'>'44788'</Param>
      <Param Id='CNL'>'BHF55'</Param>           
 </Info>
```

Сейчас получаю такой результат:

```
      <Info>
          <Param Id='CNL'>'BHF55'</Param>           
      </Info>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто вы добавляете элементы после, а добавлять их  надо внутри цикла.
Получится примерно как то так:

```
...
cXmlStr:='<Version="2.3">
          <BillCode>ATTRIBUTES</BillCode>
          <Info>';
for ac in (select a.CODE, a.value
             from M_MUNORD_ADD a
           where a.code is not null  
             and a.ID = iId)
loop
    cXmlStr:= cXmlStr||'<Param Id='||ac.code||'>'||ac.value||'</Param>'
end loop;    

cXmlStr:= cXmlStr || '</Info>'
...
```

Если oracle 11 и старше, то можно относительно легко обойтись одним sql запросом:

```
select '<Info>' ||
          listagg('<Param Id='''|| a.CODE ||'''>'''|| a.value ||'''</Param>') 
              WITHIN GROUP (order by 1) || 
      '</Info>'as xml
  from M_MUNORD_ADD a
 where a.code is not null  
   and a.ID = 48
```

что вернет вам строку:

```
<Info><Param Id='BIN'>'44788'</Param><Param Id='CNL'>'BHF55'</Param><Param Id='SUMM'>'47800'</Param></Info>
```

В принципе так можно весь xml собрать без отдельной процедуры.

PS
Так же советую посмотреть на модули для работы с xml в оракле, скорее всего его можно собрать еще проще

Comment: Или можно использовать dbms_xmlgen

Comment: @Viktorov, а как выбрать первый попавшийся  элемент то есть в данном случае SUMM  | 47800  с цикла и записать в теге <Target>'||ac.first||'</Target>

Comment: дописать в `sql запрос` в блок `where` условие `rownum < 2`. Так будет взята только первая запись по условию